# How can I get a list of all windows recognized executable extensions in cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to get a list of all the file extensions that a windows machine will recognize as an executable.

I tried the following in command prompt:

```
echo %PATHEXT%
```

But all I got from that is:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Which is not a complete list. It's missing things like:

```
.SCR;.REG;.VB;.VBSCRIPT
```

and so on.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It is not the command prompt that determines this, but rather the shell. You might try using `assoc` and/or `ftype` to figure out if a file is executable. I could give you a better answer if you explained *why* you wanted this information—what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to know what file extensions are recognized as executable. We know that .exe, .bat and so on are executable. We also know that .txt is not an executable. I want the computer to tell me what file types it recognizes as executable. Theoretically I can make my own file extension that executes lets call it  .bacon. How would you know it's an executable?

Answer (score 1):

If the extension is not in `%PATHEXT%`, then there is no association. If you just type `the.vbs` at the command line, you will be informed of same.

If you type `cscript the.vbs`, then the script will run; assuming cscript.exe is somewhere in the `PATH` variable.

In short, files such as .SCR;.REG;.VB;.VBSCRIPT are not actually executable. It is the `association` that is used to know which executable can run them.