# How to get a full list of all executable file types

Tags: windows

I am trying to setup domain controller policies to prevent users from executing anything other than the already installed programs.

There are some good guidelines out there showing how a domain controller can be used to push policies to clients, but none seem to show a full list of all executables that need to be disallowed. All policies set in place are only effective as long as the threat extension is on the checklist.

There are some obvious extensions that are missing on the default list on the software restrictions policy, such as .vb, .vbs, .ps1. .jse...

**My question is:**
Is there a way to get a dump from the OS, maybe the registry of a complete list of associations and extensions that can potentially execute unwanted code?

Note to mods:
Would you be so kind not to close this thread? There is a similar closed thread here:
[How can I get a list of all windows recognized executable extensions in cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776440/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-windows-recognized-executable-extensions-in-cmd)

I was not able to find any information anywhere else and this seems to be the right place for such information to get documented.

Comment: I think this is impossible. Apart from .exe and .dll, most other file types do not contain native executable code. Instead, there is an executable program (e.g. cmd.exe, java.exe, cscript.exe) that reads the other file types (e.g. .bat, .jar, .vbs), which contain what can be considered as textual or bytecode data to the executable program. There is nothing other than convention to stop one of these executable programs reading any random file type. For example, you can execute a .txt file by renaming a jar to .txt and typing `java -jar file.txt`.

Comment: Got it, thank you....

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing anti malware for webserver and up to this stage, it seems that it will be difficult to determine whether a file is executable or not, because in the unix family, a folder or an archive file can be executable.

Files with any extension can be executed by changing the configuration slightly, for Apache using .htaccess and Windows via the registry.

My solution to handle the scanning process running fast but not limiting only certain files being scanned is to take the first few characters of all files, such as 'MZ' on Windows, '<?php' on Apache and 'ELF' on Linux.